# Add link in sku (Magento2)

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, php-7

I have created column name **sku** in custom grid.

Set href for sku values.

If i click the sku link,it does not go to desire page.

It go to desire page when i press right click and open the link in new tab.

**In layout:**

```
<column name="product_sku" class="Xxx\Stock\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Product">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sku</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

**In Product file:**

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {              
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {                    
                    $productId = $this->_product->getIdBySku($item[$fieldName]);
                    $html = "<a  href='" . $this->context->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['id' => $productId]) . "' >";
                    $html .= $item[$fieldName];
                    $html .= "</a>";
                    $item[$fieldName] = $html;
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for it?

Comment: Updated my post .

Comment: did you check that you're getting correct URL in HREF?

Comment: Yes...It go to desire page when i press right click and open the link in new tab.

Comment: i also add target='_blank' ..it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {              
            if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {                    
                $productId = $this->_product->getIdBySku($item[$fieldName]);
                $html = "<a href='" . $this->context->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['id' => $productId]) . "' target='_blank' >";
                $html .= $item[$fieldName];
                $html .= "</a>";
                $item[$fieldName] = $html;
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that...it does not work

Comment: It’s should work.. you might be adding ‘target=_blank’ in wrong way